# Adding some bullet points to my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can i add bullet points to my application as shown below.

something like this;

I will have a String in the format of "one , list item, list item" i need it to be broken down to -

- one
- List item
- List item

Comment: I don't know what you mean. In that image all I see is asterisk characters '*'

Comment: Ok, consider it as a Bullet point as i have added in the question. :)

Comment: @sharon Don't forget to accept answers if they worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Unicode characters:

```
NSString *stringWithBullets = @"\u00b7 one";
```

will produce:

• one

Answer (score 3):

I've used this to make a bullet list from a NSMutableArray of NSString's and display it in a UITextView:

```
   NSMutableArray * items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1:00",@"2:00",@"3:00",@"4:00",@"5:00",@"6:00",@"7:00",@"8:00",@"9:00",@"10:00",@"11:00",@"12:00", nil];

    NSMutableString * bulletList = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:items.count*10];

    for (NSString *aString in items)
    {
        [bulletList appendFormat:@"\n\u2022 %@", aString]; //\u2022 bullet symbol
    }

    self.myTextView.text = bulletList;
```

Also check out the Unicode characters:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters